# What is the minimum product of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, quadratics

$a$ and $b$ are positive numbers

$$a + b = 13$$

According to this, what is the minimum product of $a$ and $b$?

I'm trying to find the easiest way to compute it.

Regards

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ positive? How about $a=13$ and $b=0$?

Comment: Yes, they are. I forgot to add them into my question.

Comment: Think about what happens when $a$ is very very close to $0$.

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: Are "numbers" whole numbers, i.e. integers, or are fractions OK?

Comment: $a$ should be $1$ then. I'm so confused right now.

Comment: Consider the parabola $13x-x^2$ for $x\in[0,13]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b=13-a$

product is $p(a)=a(13-a)$

if $a$ varies from $0$ to $13$ then product $p$ varies from $0$ to $\dfrac{169}{4}$ when $a=\dfrac{13}{2}$

If you want $a,b$ positive the domain of $a$ is open that is $0<a\le 13$ therefore there exist no minimum for the product but just the so called *infimum*

This means that the product goes down near to zero but is never zero because $a>0$

Minimum does not exist

Hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: @Lagranian From the plot I added to my answer you can see that product is maximum when  $a=b=\dfrac{13}{2}$ and product is $$ab=\left(\dfrac{13}{2}\right)^2=\dfrac{169}{4}$$

Comment: Got it now =) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since $a+b=13$, then $b=13-a$ and $ab=a(13-a)$ is a quadratic trinomial with a maximum at the vertex of parabola, i.e. for $a=6.5$. The value is $6.5^2=42.25$. The minimum does not exist if we consider all $a\in\Bbb R$. If we restrict ourselves to nonnegative $a,b$, then the minimum is zero. Maybe, may not, the question was about maximum? The minimum depends on the domain of considerations.

Comment: I wouldn't call $a(13-a)$ a trinomial.

Comment: A quadratic trinomial (in a variable $x$) has the form $\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma$, so $a(13-a)=-a^2+13a+0$ is a quadratic trinomia in $a$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ and $b$ are restricted to integers (also known as *whole* numbers), the only possibilities for $a+b$ you have to check are:
$$\begin{align}
1&+12\\
2&+11\\
3&+10\\
4&+9\\
5&+8\\
6&+7\\
7&+6\\
8&+5\\
9&+4\\
10&+3\\
11&+2\\
12&+1
\end{align}$$